# Is it possible to Initilize Debugger in Gnat GPS with the keyboard?

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

I am trying to make operating my IDEs more mouse independent, since I have a problem with my right wrist and want to minimize using the mouse as much as possible. I therefore bought a Logitec G13 game pad and I am assigning all kinds of complex keyboard macros to it to make them one-click.

I tried to initialize the debugger in Gnat GPS Studio as well using the Edit->Key Shortcuts dialog. The only possible point there is Menus->Debug/Initialize which I have bound to a a key, yet when I press the key nothing happens (I tried different keys to make sure its not the key). When activating it with the mouse, you have to chose a submenu entry to the right of Debug/Initialize and I suppose that's the reason it doesn't work. Yet, if it is impossible to initiate the debugger mode with a key, why offer that point at all in the Editor?

Is there a way to set Gnat studio in the debugger mode by using any from of keystroke only combination?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you haven't set a Main in your project file, as in:

```
for Main use ("foo.adb");
```

When you do, the /Debug/Initialize menu will have a submenu which contains "foo", and this is associated with the action "debug initialize foo". You can bind that action with a key shortcut
via the Key shortcuts dialog, or use the omni-search at the top-right corner to type the name of the action if you don't want to have a permanent key binding to it (in Emacs, mode, using M-x will set the focus in the omni-search and only search amongst the actions, so you can type "M-x difoo" or some such to start the debugger fast -- if you do not have M-x, bind it to the action "Global search in context: actions"

Comment: Thanks, but no, I have a main file. I should have pointed out that it is possible to initiate the debugger with the mouse by going to Debug->Initialize and then selecting my main program in the submenu to the right